# How is a question prefix determined?

Tags: support, tags

Pick some question tagged [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) and [voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort) like this: [Why didn't the basilisk bite in Chamber of Secrets destroy the Horcrux?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8659/why-didnt-the-basilisk-bite-in-chamber-of-secrets-destroy-the-horcrux)

If you open it, the browser tab will be titled

> **harry potter** - Why Didn't the Basilisk Bite in Chamber of Secrets
>   Destroy the Horcrux?

Pick another question that is also tagged [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) and [voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort) like this one: [How Did Harry Become a Horcrux?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/how-did-harry-become-a-horcrux)

Now the browser tab is titled

> **voldemort** - How Did Harry Become a Horcrux?

What sort of algorithm was used to determine the browser tab's title prefix? Why are some questions prefixed with **harry potter** and others with **voldemort** and others with yet another different Harry Potter relatd tag?

I imagined that the most popular tag would be the one used for the prefix, and yet the [voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort) one appears to prevail over the [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) one in some cases.

If it is some sort of bug, it should be easy to fix by always prioritizing [voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort) over [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter).

Comment: I'm not sure this matters in terms of the goals of all the stacks: to make the internet a better place. It might be a bug, probably someone will know. And Harry is not a Horcrux. ;)

Comment: It's just the biggest (i.e. most questions) tag, unless that tag is already part of the title, which I guess is the reason for using `voldemort` in your second example. There's a canonical [meta.se] answer saying exactly that which I currently have a hard time finding (I think it's from *Anna Lear*).

Comment: Ah, here it is: [How is the page title tag determined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180382/162011).

Comment: @TARS that should be an answer :)

Comment: ROFL at the last line! :-D